# How to show the current filename in each split window's status line in Vim?

Tags: windows, vim, split, statusline

I have a global statusline set, but it would be useful if each split window had the current filename in its own statusline.

Comment: Each window has its own statusline showing informations pertaining to the buffer currently displayed in that window. In other words, what you want is the default behavior. Please show us your `set statusline` and tell us what's the value of `laststatus`.

Comment: This is in stock vim (7.3.) that ships with Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks). Im using the Syntastic plugin which adds to `statusline`:
`set statusline+=%#warningmsg#`
`set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}`
`set statusline+=%*`
I dont explicitly set `laststatus` but I see it has the value of `2`.
I do see a status line but not for individual vim windows.

Comment: [This](http://i.imgur.com/k12EN45.png) is what I get with `$ /usr/bin/vim -u NONE .bashrc -c "vs .ctags" -c "sp .tmux.conf"`. Note the three filenames. If you don't have something similar add all the details you can to your question.

Comment: While the above works for me, I am using the NERDTree plugin, so I'll often just fire up vim (no filenames on cmd line) and just use the sidebar to navigate to and open files in new split windows but these new windows [dont have local status lines](http://i.imgur.com/nzApgGr.png). On second thoughts, maybe this is a limitation with the NERDTree plugin...

Comment: Wait! Your statusline is empty, no wonder you don't have filenames displayed. You should read `:help 'statusline'`.

Comment: Which means the default `statusline` on my machine is empty.

Answer (score 10):

OK, the default setting is empty so I added the following setting for stock console vim that seems to play nice with the NERDTree and Syntastic plugins:

```
" [buffer number] followed by filename:
set statusline=[%n]\ %t
" for Syntastic messages:
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*
" show line#:column# on the right hand side
set statusline+=%=%l:%c
```

Comment: very nice -> surprised there are fewer upvotes on this. I'm currently learning Elixir's Phoenix web framework, and it forces work on many interdependent small files, so this is almost indispensable.

Comment: how would you refresh this - running from inside tmux then this status will disappear when moving between tmux panes ?

Comment: @serup Im using screen with split panes (basically a main window with vim running in it and a smaller pane below which is just a bash command-line). I looked at replicating this setup with tmux, but you can't do with a single file the way you can with screen, so I stayed with screen.